# Java - Combine multiple list data into single separate column list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to know if it is possible to combine data in different streams into a single stream. By combine i mean adding it into separate columns not to the existing column.

So far I have been able to collect the data into separate Maps as shown in the example below. I believe I should combine these Maps into a single one, but not sure how to go about it or whether I am doing something wrong.

I did some searching, found some threads on FlatMap, Concat etc. but since I am new to this Streams & Map features I seek guidance. (At present I have this working without using Map / Streams feature, just using the standard List with Add & AddALL )

Eg:
List data - 1 `Map<String, int> carMileage`

- [carOne, 10]
- [carTwo, 20]
- [carThree, 25]

List data - 2 `Map<String, String> carGearBox`

- [carThree, automatic]
- [carTwo, manual]
- [carOne, mixed]

List data - 3 `Map<String, Double> carMaxSpeed`

- [carTwo, 160.75]
- [carThree, 200.25]
- [carOne, 250.55]

Output : [something like: `Map<String, dataCar>` ]

- [carOne, 10, mixed, 250.55]
- [carTwo, 20, manual, 160.75]
- [carThree, 25, automatic, 200.25]

Comment: you ask how to merge maps, but maybe it would be easier to get desired result without these maps? how does the data source look like? is it a sql.ResultSet?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker the dataset is coming from several excel files. Eventually I plan to replace excel data with MySQL, but for now I am extracting data from Excel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming all 3 maps have the same set of keys, the direct solution would be to create a Stream over the entries of one map (for example `carMileage`) and collect it into another map of `DataCar`. If there is a constructor `DataCar(mileAge, String gearBox, Double maxSpeed)`, you could have the following:

```
Map<String, DataCar> result =
    carMileage.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> new DataCar(e.getValue(), carGearBox.get(e.getKey()), carMaxSpeed.get(e.getKey()))
              ));
```